# What is the inverse Python os operation to os.path._getfinalpathname(r"C:\Windows")?

Tags: python

In Python `os.path._getfinalpathname(r"C:\Windows")` returns `\\\\?\\C:\\Windows`.
How can I get `C:\Windows` from `\\\\?\\C:\\Windows` using `os`, not string manipulations such as `"\\\\?\\C:\\Windows".replace("\\\\?\\", "")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathlib.Path.resolve` can help:

```
from pathlib import Path

original = r"C:\Windows"
final = os.path._getfinalpathname(original)  # \\?\C:\Windows
resolved = Path(final).resolve()             # C:\Windows
```

As docs say, `Path.resolve` is similar but different from `os.path.abspath`; the latter can't do this.